# CentOS: Admin user on xrdp session can't do admin

Tags: centos, vnc, sysadmin, xrdp, rocky-linux

I'm running a Rocky Linux 8.4 workstation with GNOME and MATE desktops, but I've seen the same problem on CentOS 7.9...

When I log into the machine on the local display, I can do things like administer users and set the system time using the Control Centre app (this on MATE, the tools are buried in the menu on GNOME).  When I click on the tool I'll get a popup asking for my password, or there will be an "unlock" button to click before I get authenticated.  This all works because my user is a member of the "wheel" administrative group.

However, when the same user logs in to the same desktop environment over `xrdp`, the ability to administer the system has gone.  In some cases the "unlock" button is greyed out, in others when I click on the tool app icon I get a message "Error executing command as another user: Not authorized" in my `.xsession-errors` file.

As I understand it, the problem is down to `polkit` treating local and remote sessions differently, and basically blocking administrative actions from remote sessions such as xrdp, vnc etc.  This is a pain, because the main reason for setting up the xrdp service was so that I *could* administer the machine remotely!  I can work around this to some extent using `sudo` from a terminal, but really I want it to Just Work™.

So my question is - how do I configure `polkit` to treat a remote session for my admin user identically to a local session?  (Always assuming that polkit is the source of my problem!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having framed yesterday's frustrations more succinctly, I used a well-known search engine to look for "linux polkit local and remote sessions" and got this as the top result - [Enabling system management privileges for non-local users - How the heck does `polkit` work, anyways?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/enabling-system-management-privileges-for-non-local-users-how-the-heck-does-p)  The answer (slightly modified from the linked question) is to create a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-remote-admin-allow.pkla` containing

```
[Allow Remote Admin]
Identity=unix-group:wheel
Action=*
ResultAny=auth_admin_keep
ResultInactive=auth_admin_keep
ResultActive=auth_admin_keep
```

and run `systemctl restart polkit` (which is vital but was missed in the other question).  You can also put this file under `/var/lib/polkit-1`, but according to [pklocalauthority.8](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html) the former is intended for local configuration while the latter is for 3rd party packages.

Answer (score 0):

Worked great for me.  Thanks!

I wasn't sure what "Identity=unix-group:**wheel**" was so I changed the group to 'sudo' instead.  I'm guessing 'users' group would have worked as well.

I'm running Linux Lite 6.0 BTW.

Cheers!

Comment: RedHat and derivatives use the “wheel” group for users who can become root. Ubuntu (and maybe other Debian derivatives) use the “sudo” group for that purpose.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  I used to run Redhat/Fedora but moved over to Ubuntu/Mint/Debian around 10 years ago on the recommendation of a friend.  Yep, "sudo" is pretty much ubiquitous in Debian land.
Do you ever run webmin?  I'm having a bizarre issue running it on the Linux Lite OS.  It ran w/o issue on Linux Mint.